# Why do I get a Segmenation Fault in my code? (C)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, user-input

I am trying to request three strings from the user, and while the first two work and go through correctly, the third one gives a Segmentation Fault while running. The first two  are pretty much identical to the third one apart from its variable name, so I am confused why it would give an error only here.

```
        printf("Input Text File Name (with .txt): \n");
        char text [50];
        scanf("%s", text);

        // Gets query from user.
        printf("Input Query Word: \n");
        char query [50];
        scanf("%s", query);

        // Gets query length
        int length = strlen(query);

        // Gets replacement word from user.
        printf("Input Replacement Word: \n");
printf("WHOOP");
        char replace [50];
printf("WHOOP2");
        scanf("%s", replace);
printf("WHOOP3");
        // For counting the number of Replacements.
        int count = 0;
printf("WHOOP4");
```

Whoop and Whoop2 both print, but Whoop 3 and 4 do not. The variables text and query both go through and print correctly, but replace is the only one that is causing problems for some reason. I have tried clearing the input buffer after each scanf, but it only results in the same thing.

I am new to c, so I might just be being dumb. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Try adding `\n` to the end of each Whoop string.

Comment: FWIW: `scanf("%s", ...)` is incredibly dangerous - an input longer than the buffer will overflow. For a toy application it doesn't matter so much, but you wouldn't believe how often this shows up in real code. Use `%49s` for better safety.

Comment: to expand on @n.m.'s point: `printf` is line-buffered by default, meaning that it only writes to the terminal if it sees a newline or if the program *exits normally*. If your program crashes, anything that you printed since the last newline will be silently lost. This is why you should always put newlines on your debug messages, or print to `stderr`.

Comment: Unless you type a word longer than 49 characters, there's nothing here that would cause a segmentation fault by itself. The problem could be elsewhere in the program. When you cause undefined behavior, the symptoms may not appear immediately.

Comment: Thank you! I added the /n (and also changed the scanf like you said) and Whoop 4 printed. It looks like you are right and the problem is actually elsewhere in the program. I'll look through and see if I can find it. Tysm for the help!

Comment: Anytime the user types more than 49 chars on each line, you risk a crash or undefined behavior.